# How solve TypeError nil can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby, typeerror

I have this code:

```
require 'set'

N, K = gets.split().map{ |v| v.to_i }
set = Set.new
numbers = gets.split().map{ |v| v.to_i }
pairs = 0

N.times do |i|
  set.add(numbers[i])
end

set.each{ |value| pairs += set.include?(value+K) ? 1 : 0 }

puts pairs
```

But when I put N and K, return this error:

```
`+': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
```

I should convert or other thing? Thanks!

Comment: So, what I do? Does not make sense to me

Comment: I think the issue here is that `numbers[i]` is nil in some case, so `set` gets `nil` pushed to it. Then when you iterate over set, `value` is nil in some case, so `value+K` fails. You can remove nil elements from an array with `.compact`, but I'm not sure this solves your problem because I don't fully understand what the goal of this code is.

Comment: the compact did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to count the number of pairs in your set that are separated by K?
Your code works when you input `3 1` followed by `1 2 3`. It answers `2`.

- First, you really should describe a bit more what your goal is.
- Then, no need to input N. It just should be the size of your set.
- Write an example of the desired input before calling `gets`

Here's a possible implementation :

```
require 'set'

puts 'Please type the integers of your set, separated by a space. Example : 1 2 3'
numbers = Set.new(gets.split.map{ |v| v.to_i})

# N=numbers.size # But you don't need it

puts 'Which pair difference are you looking for? Example : 1'
k = gets.to_i

pairs = numbers.select{|value| numbers.include?(value+k)}

count = pairs.size

puts "#{count} pair(s) found :"

pairs.each{|first_value|
  puts format("(%d, %d)",first_value,first_value+k)
} 

# Please type the integers of your set, separated by a space. Example : 1 2 3
# 1 2 3
# Which pair difference are you looking for? Example : 1
# 1
# 2 pair(s) found :
# (1, 2)
# (2, 3)
```